# Php header in targeted id

Tags: php

It give me a headache for a while

this is my form

```
<form action="insert_info.php" method="POST">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname"/><br/>
```

insert_info.php

```
<?php "some codes here"
Header("Location: edit_info.php");
```

how can i make the header to target it like this or in a certain id

```
"edit_info.php?id=".$row['id']
```

Comment: What's preventing you from doing just that? `header("Location: edit_info.php?id=" . $row['id']);` ?

Comment: Are you trying to submit a form to `edit_info.php`?

Comment: @Epodax Notice: Undefined index: id in it will give me like this

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala nope just editing some data

Comment: .... well, you need to fetch the data? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it ;-)

```
header("Location: edit_info.php?id=" . $row['id']);
```